# Using safeargs I get "required Bundle found Bundle?"

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-safe-args

I am passing arguments using safeargs. In the reciving fragment I am getting a compile error: 'Required Bundle Found Bundle?'. Cannot see where the error has crept in.

Googled around, checked text and udacity tutorial

Where error appears (at 'arguments')

```
package com.example.android.naveditoryoutube

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_two_fragment.*

class FragmentTwo : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FragmentTwo()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: FragmentTwoViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FragmentTwoViewModel::class.java)

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments)
        argText.text = args.calculated_Number
    }

}
```

Sending code:

```
package com.example.android.naveditoryoutube

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_one_fragment.*


class FragmentOne : Fragment() {


    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FragmentOne()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: FragmentOneViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_fragment, container, false)

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FragmentOneViewModel::class.java)

        var calculated_Number : String = viewModel.sendNewNumber().toString()

        button_calculate.setOnClickListener{view: View ->
            if (number_box.text.isNotEmpty()){
                var number_entered: String = number_box.text.toString()
                viewModel.findNewNumber((number_entered))
                calculated_Number = viewModel.sendNewNumber()
               Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(FragmentOneDirections.actionFragmentOneToFragmentTwo(calculated_Number))
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Error appears here
 var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments)

arguments is expected to be Bundle but is Bundle?

Comment: What is FragmentTwoArgs?

Comment: `arguments` is nullable and they are expecting non-null. Time to solve it!!

Comment: FragmentTwoArgs was set up (in generated java folder) when I posted the following lines in gradle files: classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha11" AND apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

Answer (score 5):

I had to change it to use !!

var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll try that if the above solution doesn't work

Comment: This is what you need if the navigation action sometimes has no argument bundle.

Answer (score 3):

use `requireArguments()` instead of `arguments!!`

Comment: Could you explain what this does and why it's preferred?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireArguments() check this. However, there is a better option if you are using safe args with nav component just make a property and initialize it like this 
val args : FragmentArgs by navArgs()

Answer (score 1):

try using requireArguments() instead of arguments

```
var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments)`
just use:

```
val args: FragmentTwoArgsby navArgs()
```

And in your method call:

```
val amount = args.amount
```

It's work for me, see official guide:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Comment: Hi Dmitry - the compile errors have vanished - Thanks very much

Comment: Using `navArgs()` requires -ktx dependencies, if you aren't using them (e.g. a Java-only project) then the method is `getArguments() `.  Also, for `navArgs()` the '`by`' keyword is required...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments)
        argText.text = args.calculated_Number`

you can use

```
arguments?.let {
                  val args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(it)
                  argText.text = args.calculated_Number
            }
```